# How to change the value of XML tag with Ti.API.XML

Tags: javascript, xml, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I'm building an app with Appcelerator Studio that can parse an XML file and can also change some elements of this document.

Now in my XML file, I have this:

```
<partecipant>
   <name>Pippo</name>
</partecipant>
```

Now I can read the value of Node "name" (Pippo) with this code:

```
var partecipant = document.getElementsByTagName('participant');
var location = partecipant.item(0).getElementsByTagName('name').item(0).text;
```

But I'm not able to change this value of this node.
I'm trying to use this code (but not works):

```
var nameNode = nameNodes.item(0); //(I get the element NAME from XML file)
nameNode.text ='PLUTO';
nameNode.textContent = 'PLUTO';
nameNode.setNodeValue('PLUTO');
```

With this code I can't change the value of the tag NAME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by changing the nodeValue of the firstChild of the node and not the node itself.

Change your code to:

```
nodeName.getFirstChild().nodeValue = 'PLUTO';
```

It worked for me.